# Matlab diff(F,var,n) vs Python numpy diff(a, n=1, axis=-1)

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I am trying to calculate matlab function in python.

```
y = diff(x,1,2)
```

x is and grayscale image

i tried numpy diff function but i get different answer

please help

Comment: Please provide some additional information. How do you call diff in MATLAB? What kind of image are you using (maybe post it as well)? How is the answer different from what you expect?

Comment: Matlab:  fimg = single(gstreet2); xdif_img = diff(fimg,1,2);   Python; fimg=fimg.astype('float32'); xdif_img=np.diff(fimg,2,1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here.

First, you swapped the order of arguments in `np.diff`.  MATLAB and Python use the same argument order.  Python supports named arguments, so it is often better to use the argument name to avoid this sort of problem.

Second, python indexing starts with 0, while MATLAB indexing starts with `1`.  This applies to axes as well, so MATLAB's axis `2` is Python's axis `1`.

So the correct function call in Python is `np.diff(fimg, 1, 1)`, but `np.diff(fimg, axis=1)` is better IMO.

MATLAB:

```
>> a = reshape(1:100, 10, [])'

a =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20
    21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28    29    30
    31    32    33    34    35    36    37    38    39    40
    41    42    43    44    45    46    47    48    49    50
    51    52    53    54    55    56    57    58    59    60
    61    62    63    64    65    66    67    68    69    70
    71    72    73    74    75    76    77    78    79    80
    81    82    83    84    85    86    87    88    89    90
    91    92    93    94    95    96    97    98    99   100

>> diff(a,1, 2)

ans =

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Python:

```
>>> a = np.arange(100).reshape(10, -1)
>>> print(a)
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29]
 [30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39]
 [40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49]
 [50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59]
 [60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69]
 [70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79]
 [80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89]
 [90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99]]
>>> print(np.diff(a, axis=1))
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

in the comment to your question, it appears you swapped the arguments to the `diff` functions. However, the documentation states that both in matlab and in numpy, the order of the arguments is:

- array
- n
- dimension